Как писать одновременно в разных столбцах гугл таблицы
Подскажите, как можно одновременно писать информацию в разных ячейках Гугл-таблицы? Например, писать в ячейке А1 и она автоматически пишется в ячейке С1

В c1 поставить формулу =A1

Вставить формулу в C
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(A:A<>"";A:A; "")) 

